# I have two 'WsusContent' folders. One has about 55gb of files in it. How do I clear it out?

Tags: wsus, system-center-essentials

I ran the WSUS cleanup wizard in the WSUS MMC snap-in but this made no difference.  I think the files are associated with System Center Essentials because they are in a folder called "data\SCE2007\WsusContent"

I've looked for a similar cleanup wizard in System Center Essentials but can't find one.  Is there a way to clear these files out that doesn't cause issues for SCE or anything else?

FYI I've got both SCE and standalone WSUS settings already set to minimize the amount of updates downloaded from Microsoft to only those that are needed.

Comment: Hi, can you post some screen shots of your configuration?